# Spring Security AccessTokenConveter never use

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to configure my Authorization Server. I need to customize my accessTokenConverter but when i set accessTokenConverter it didn't work. He don't take my accessTokenConverter.

My code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("Storage")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
            .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
            .secret("secret")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(30000)
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(60000);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager).pathMapping("/oauth/token", "/connect").accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
    }


    public AccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        return new myAccessToken();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }
}
```

I set it in the endpoint but it is not use. any idea?